# build and executable jar using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a simple Scala command line `App` that I want to package using SBT.

```
object Transform extends App {
  val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(args(0))
  ...
}
```

I can't seem to find anything in the SBT docs or an online example of a SBT configuration/command that would allows me to create a standalone executable jar (`java -jar ...`) with the appropriate manifest and dependencies included.

I did find [SBT Assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), but it looks to be a plugin for SBT < 0.13.5.

Comment: As I know, `sbt-assembly` works fine with sbt 0.13. But you can also find some alternatives at sbt docs: [Community Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community-Plugins.html#One+jar+plugins)

Answer (score 0):

[sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) was created for exactly this use case.